# Why button inside on the cell "RowDataBound" is not firing the event click?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm implementing a gridview with button inside each cell. But I can't recognize why the buttons inside the cell on a gridview are not firing. I used the gridview RowDataBound and RowCommand to check if the buttons is firing. I also create a button outside the gridview but it works as expected. I can't really understand why the button on the gridview cell is not firing once clicked.

Generate the gridview on code-behind.

```
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

dataTable.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[32]
{
            new DataColumn("Month"),
            new DataColumn("Day1"),
            new DataColumn("Day2"),
            new DataColumn("Day3"),
            new DataColumn("Day4"),
            new DataColumn("Day5"),
            new DataColumn("Day6"),
            new DataColumn("Day7"),
            new DataColumn("Day8"),
            new DataColumn("Day9"),
            new DataColumn("Day10"),
            new DataColumn("Day11"),
            new DataColumn("Day12"),
            new DataColumn("Day13"),
            new DataColumn("Day14"),
            new DataColumn("Day15"),
            new DataColumn("Day16"),
            new DataColumn("Day17"),
            new DataColumn("Day18"),
            new DataColumn("Day19"),
            new DataColumn("Day20"),
            new DataColumn("Day21"),
            new DataColumn("Day22"),
            new DataColumn("Day23"),
            new DataColumn("Day24"),
            new DataColumn("Day25"),
            new DataColumn("Day26"),
            new DataColumn("Day27"),
            new DataColumn("Day28"),
            new DataColumn("Day29"),
            new DataColumn("Day30"),
            new DataColumn("Day31")
});

DataRow dataRow;

var months = new string[] { "JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC" };

for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();

    dataRow["Month"] = months[i];

    for (int j = 0; j < 30; j++)
    {
    }

    dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
}

GridView.DataSource = dataTable;
GridView.DataBind();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        LoadDataSources();
    }
}
```

Render the button on the cell.

```
protected void GridViewPricing_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 31; i++)
        {
            var button = new Button();
            button.ID = string.Format("{0}", i);
            button.Attributes.Add("style", "display:block; padding:4px; width:100%; height:100%;");

            button.CommandName = "ButtonCell";
            button.CommandArgument = "ButtonCell";

            e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(button);
        }
    }
}
```

Test if the button is firing once clicked.

```
protected void ButtonCell_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("Button Click");
}

protected void GridViewPricing_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("Button Click");
}
```

This is for view.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView"
runat="server"
AutoGenerateColumns="false"
CellPadding="0"
CellSpacing="0"
OnRowDataBound="GridViewPricing_RowDataBound"
OnRowCommand="GridViewPricing_RowCommand">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Month" HeaderText="" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Day1" HeaderText="1" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Day2" HeaderText="2" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Day3" HeaderText="3" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Day4" HeaderText="4" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Day5" HeaderText="5" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Day6" HeaderText="6" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Day7" HeaderText="7" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Day8" HeaderText="8" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Day9" HeaderText="9" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Day10" HeaderText="10" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Day11" HeaderText="11" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Day12" HeaderText="12" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Day13" HeaderText="13" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Day14" HeaderText="14" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Day15" HeaderText="15" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Day16" HeaderText="16" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Day17" HeaderText="17" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Day18" HeaderText="18" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Day19" HeaderText="19" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Day20" HeaderText="20" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Day21" HeaderText="21" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Day22" HeaderText="22" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Day23" HeaderText="23" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Day24" HeaderText="24" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Day25" HeaderText="25" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Day26" HeaderText="26" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Day27" HeaderText="27" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Day28" HeaderText="28" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Day29" HeaderText="29" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Day30" HeaderText="30" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Day31" HeaderText="31" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Remove the `IsPostBack` check around `LoadDataSources();`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Add button before closing tag of `columns` element

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Day31" HeaderText="31" />
  <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button"  CommandName="ButtonCommandName" HeaderText="Buttons" 
     ShowHeader="True" Text="Click Me" ItemStyle-Width="30px" />
</Columns>
```

In your GridView_RowCommand

```
protected void GridViewPricing_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
     int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
      GridViewRow gvRow = GridViewPricing.Rows[index];
     if (e.CommandName == "ButtonCommandName")
      {
          //Your Code here something like 
           gvRow.Cells[0].Text

      }
}
```

Comment: it's working. but I want render the button entire cell except Month Name, Column Days.

Comment: Your problem is just button click event.. if this is working and help your problem then you can make it as answered.